# Where does the streamed video resides in client's PC

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, firefox-addon, video-streaming

I was watching yahoo videos (movies) and tried to download it using Firefox Add-on - "Video DownloadHelper"

But it was unable to download it.

Then I tried to download it using "Orbit video downloader" and clicked on "GetIt" button and found that the url is null. (I tried both Firefox and IE)

But there must be some folder where the streamed video use to resides (in client's PC). Can any one tell me the location where exactly these streamed videos resides in client's PC?

Answer (score 0):

They don't reside on your computer, or it would not be called streaming. What you refer to is called downloading (then playing).

Comment: Understood, but what about cached videos after streaming is done. I had observed that after the entire video has been streamed, if you try to play it again then it will playing without streaming it back. It means it must be cached somewhere in your PC. But where exactly? and in which format?

Comment: It must have some storage place from where it runs the file without streaming it back from the server